# Persist data for MySQL pod using Persistent Volume through cluster restarts

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I am trying to deploy a MySQL deployment on Kubernetes and would like to persist data. I am currently able to persist data through the lifetime of the pod (kubectl delete and then kubectl create). However, I am unable to persist data through cluster restarts. Any idea why this is the case?

**persistent-volume.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
 name: mysql-pv-volume
spec:
 storageClassName: hostpath
 persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
 capacity:
  storage: 100Mi
 accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
 hostPath:
  path: "/mnt/data"
```

**persistent-volume-claim.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
 name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
 storageClassName: hostpath
 accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
 resources:
  requests:
   storage: 100Mi
```

**mysql-deployment.yml**

````
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: powerplus-db
spec:
  serviceName: powerplus-db
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: powerplus-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: powerplus-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: powerplus-db
          image: mysql:8.0.21
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: password
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: powerplus
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: powerplus-db
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
              name: mysql-persistent-storage
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv-claim```
````

Comment: What kubernetes are you running? how do you restart your cluster

Comment: @Matt I am using Docker Desktop for Windows' Kubernetes Cluster. I simply restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

This case is well described in [this official guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/), especially in paragraph regarding [Create PersistentVolumeClaims and PersistentVolumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-):

> Warning: In local clusters, the default `StorageClass` uses the `hostPath`
> provisioner. `hostPath` volumes are only suitable for development and
> testing. With `hostPath` volumes, your data lives in `/tmp` on the node
> the Pod is scheduled onto and does not move between nodes. If a Pod
> dies and gets scheduled to another node in the cluster, or the node is
> rebooted, the data is lost.

`HostPath` is being used for single node testing purposes only. You way want to use a different type of `PersisstentVolume`.
You can find more details regarding the `PersistentVolumes` types [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes).